# Kernel Error during upgrade or update commands

Tags: 13.04, kernel

I am getting these errors during `sudo apt-get update and upgrade`... I tried all possible options no success. I recently upgraded to 13.04 and had problems with Broadcom WiFi. Fixed tat issues using the clean script... but looks like it did not install the Kernel properly.. Here is the o/p of the few scripts I ran:

```
ashesh@ashesh-HPdv4:~$ sudo dpkg -r bcmwl-kernel-source
(Reading database ... 175338 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bcmwl-kernel-source ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-25-generic
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/mtd/mtd.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/mtd/mtd.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/sfc/sfc.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/sfc/sfc.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx4/mlx4_core.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx4/mlx4_core.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/bnx2x/bnx2x.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/bnx2x/bnx2x.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/cnic.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/cnic.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/qlogic/netxen/netxen_nic.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/qlogic/netxen/netxen_nic.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/brocade/bna/bna.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/brocade/bna/bna.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/libfc/libfc.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/libfc/libfc.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/advansys.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/advansys.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/be2iscsi/be2iscsi.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/be2iscsi/be2iscsi.ko’: Input/output error
cp: reading ‘/lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/bnx2i/bnx2i.ko’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/tmp/mkinitramfs_8gjKwQ//lib/modules/3.8.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/bnx2i/bnx2i.ko’: Input/output error
Bus error (core dumped)
depmod: ../libkmod/libkmod-elf.c:207: elf_get_mem: Assertion `offset < elf->size' failed.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am not a techie but I need your support to resolve this without re-installation from scratch....

Comment: That's hard to read. Can you post the log file instead?

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: Do a fresh install.

Long answer: I know this may seem discouraging, but to date only one of my upgrades of Ubuntu has been entirely successful. I have been using Ubuntu since version 8.04 or 8.10, and I have always, except for one time, first tried upgrading and then ended up doing a fresh install after backing up everything that matters to me. I barely have anything on my computer that is not constantly synced to a cloud service or backed up on an external device.

My experience leads me to believe that my misfortune has been caused by excessive customization of my computer and user interface, so now I tend mostly to refrain from this. Good luck!